# How SLA of 99.95% works for Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

As per the Microsoft [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/app-service/v1_4/), the SLA for App Service is 99.95%. Is this SLA valid for a given region in which the App Service is created? or is it a general SLA?

SLA of 99.95% has a downtime of 21 mins 36 seconds. Now, if I create an App Service in West Europe and if that region has a major outage, does that mean Azure will automatically re-create my App Service in another reason without changing DNS or any configuration?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a commercial question, not a programming question

Comment: It is more of an architectural question and not commercial.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question. Programming is more than coding, you need to know how reliable your code is in production. Then this question on SLA is relevant, and it has a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this SLA valid for a given region in which the App Service is
> created? or is it a general SLA?

Yes it is valid for a given region where the app service is created

> Does that mean Azure will automatically re-create my App Service in
> another reason without changing DNS or any configuration?

No , you need to have a secondary site configured in another region and reroute the users to that particular site whenever a major outage happens

Comment: Its a general SLA for WebApp not tied to a region.

Comment: It's regional , if you deploy to West US then SLA is given for that

Comment: @sajeetharan, does that mean, if I want to withstand the region-level failure, I will have to create two web apps in two different regions and maintain them individually? Also, two web app means two different URLs and that means, I will have to inform my users to switch the URLs in case of failover?

Comment: Yes thats right! having zero downtime application is customer's responsibility. You can enable slot deployment and have some load balancer services to route the users. Here is the recommended architecture https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region

Answer (score -2):

SLA is different for various service in Azure and also depends on the plan/tier that you have choosed.

SLA depends on lot of factor

- server location
- DR plan
- Load balancer
- network latency

Example - Azure cognitive service might have higher SLA than App service, because the server infrastructure, disatory recovery all handled and created by microsoft itself so it will have almost 99.9 but for app service we choose what infrastructure we want and back up,etc.

Hope it clarifies.